# Sharepoint Toolpart Values Not Being Retrieved

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, toolpart

I am looking to add custom properties to a tool part.  I've been able to add the textbox as desired.  I've been able to enter values and display it in the webpart.

The problem is when I edit the webpart - the panel pops up but the control I added is not populated with the previously entered value.  See below:

[image: Why doesn't this work? :(]

I have followed the instructions [on this website](http://www.dhirajranka.com/?p=420) exactly as written - neither myself nor a more experienced Sharepoint developer co-worker is able to figure out what's going on here.

We thought that overriding the SyncChanges() method would allow for this - It seems it doesn't, unless our implementation isn't correct?

```
    public override void SyncChanges()
    {
        DemoWebPart wp = (DemoWebPart)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
        urls.Text = wp.ListValue;
    }
```

We have also prefixed the urls property of the DemoWebPart.cs class with the following, to no avail:

```
    [Browsable(true), Category("Miscellaneous"),
    DefaultValue("Site Names"),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared / Personal / None),
    FriendlyName("URLs"), Description("Text Property")]
```

(Having tried Storage.Shared, Storage.Personal, and Storage.None).

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I generally use for such properties:

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Custom")]
[WebDisplayName("DisplayNameGoesHere")]
[WebDescription("Type the description of this web property here.")]
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: Just tried this...now it no longer saves what I type into the textbox to display in the webpart...

Comment: Temporarily clear out all of the stuff that you've posted in the OP to make sure they're not conflicting with each other.  (The sync changes in particular.)

Answer (score 1):

Only use the following if Webpart personalization is enbaled in central admin:

```
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)
```

If it is not, remove the Personalizable attribute completely.  Do not put in false or none in it, delete that attribute and use this:

```
WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :

1. Create a new WP
2. and use this article http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/11/webpart-custom-properties.html

I have used this 100s of times , please give it try , it will work.

Thanks
Sandeep